# Passing data variable in Fancybox to iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I am trying but failing to pass a variable through JS to an iframe. The purpose of the frames does the following. I take a list of safe external urls if the url that has been clicked is not on the safe list then open a fancybox with a special message to alert the user that the link they clicked does not share in the site's opinions or views. Also there is a continue button in the iframe that has the url they originally clicked on uses php echo $_GET['dest']; to get the url form the iframe url.

The code below works in chrome but in FF and IE I get

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /wp-content/themes/mytheme/third-party-alert.php on this server.**

I am not sure how to solve the forbidden message so I thought I could try and pass the url that they clicked in the data attribute for Fancybox and then reuse it in the iframe. I have tried multiple attempts to pass the data but keep failing. How do I pass the data of the url they clicked into the iframe (which is just a page that is being displayed as an iframe) and use it as the a href link in the iframe page so if the user wishes to continue on they can by clicking the button.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Put anonymous functions and other stuff in here.

  // qTip notice of external link
  jQuery.each(jQuery('a'),function(){
    // Check if it's a URL not owned/operated by GBFCU
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    url = (url==null) ? '' : url.split('://');
    if(url.length>1){
        url = url[1].split('/');
        // List the "safe URLs" here.
        if(url[0]!= 'www.safeurl.org' &&
            url[0]!= 'safeurl.org' &&
            url[0]!= 'lastsafeurl.net' 
            ){  
                // Display confirmation for "not safe" URLs.
                var dest = jQuery(this).attr('href');                   
                dest = encodeURIComponent(dest);
                jQuery(this).on('click',function(){
                    var speciallink = dest;

                        jQuery.fancybox( {
                            href : '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/third-party-alert.php?dest='+dest,
                            type : 'iframe',
                            padding : 0,
                            autoSize : false,
                            width: '600px',
                            height : '520px',
                            scrolling : 'no',
                            data : dest                 
                        });                             

                    return false;
                });                 

                jQuery(this).attr('target','_blank');               
        }//if not safe...
    }//if it's an http:// link      
});//iterate through all the hyperlinks on the page 
});
```

Comment: It's weird that you get that message in FF and IE but not Chrome because it is a server error. Could you try clearing your cache in all browsers? Maybe one of them is caching a older version of the javascript file.

Comment: Is /wp-content/themes/mytheme/third-party-alert.php the correct file? Can you view that file directly in your browser?

Comment: @Andrew yes - /wp-content/themes/mytheme/third-party-alert.php is the correct file and if I view that file in all browsers I do not get the forbidden error. If I add the additional query string to it then I get the forbidden.  ex -/wp-content/themes/mytheme/third-party-alert.php?dest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lovemycreditunion.org%2Fclient%2Flove_my_cu%2Fbanner%2F%3Fbid%3D1054%26campid%3D35%26clientid%3D7063%26sid%3D1

Comment: Did you try clearing your cache? I don't know what else could cause the problem you are having.

Comment: @Andrew yes, I cleared it in both browsers. My only other through is an htaccess or server permissions setting that might throw the conflict. Thoughts?

 Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't have a clue. What if you past 1 for dest?

Comment: @Andrew I think I may have figured out an important step. If I am logged into the WP admin and have the admin panel then the page displays in every browser. When I am logged out I always get the forbidden error in every browser.

Comment: @andrew I think I solved the problem, it was a setting in iThemes Security. Someone checked a box that would not allow query strings to be passed. Thus it failed for any non admin user.... sorry for wasting any of you time and thank you for your help.

Comment: ooh that makes sends. Glad you got it cleared up.